# lftp: where are bookmarks stored on debian jessie?

Tags: bookmarks, debian-jessie, lftp

Bookmarks are saved but I get an empty (new file) when I run `bookmark edit` inside lftp and I don't have any `~/.lftp/bookmarks` file.

For information, I add bookmarks like this:

```
$ lftp sftp://username@mysitehost
$ password:
lftp> bookmark add mysite
lftp> exit
```

and then I can use the bookmark like this

```
$ lftp mysite
$ password:
lftp>
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite running lftp as a regular user, I found that lftp actually stores the bookmarks in root's files (despite `lftp> bookmark edit` opening a blank file).

Check:

```
/root/.local/share/lftp/bookmarks
```

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays the bookmarks are stored in the file `~/.local/share/lftp/bookmarks`

You can still edit them with

```
lftp
bookmark edit
```